# Vlookup on WorksheetFunction blocking my form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, vlookup, lookup

I have inherited an excel file with a form that has to be filled with TextBox, ComboBox, Buttons, etc. and the form, when submitted, would fill the information on a table on a separate sheet from column A to AM.

Recently, I wanted to improve this report and tried to add new ComboBoxes and this info should go to columns AN and AO. The print code I added was the last two lines, which is the same as the previous ones on the Form Code but I keep getting the following error message:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYP5O.png)

```
 .ReparadoComboBox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.CodigoComboBox), Sheet3.Range("Lookup"), 15, 0)

.EquipaRComboBox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.CodigoComboBox), Sheet3.Range("Lookup"), 39, 0)

.AreaEquipComboBox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.CodigoComboBox), Sheet3.Range("Lookup"), 40, 0)

.ModoFalhaComboBox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.CodigoComboBox), Sheet3.Range("Lookup"), 41, 0)
```

I believe the answer is on the Range of the VLookup, but I can't find anywhere where it is defined

Comment: How many columns does `Sheet3.Range("Lookup")` have?

Comment: I don't know, where can I check that? I think that is the issue and if I add two more columns I'll fix the issue

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Sheet3.Range("Lookup").Columns.Count` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Thanks, it is 39 columns. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: You can do that from the Formulas > Name Manager ribbon option. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMYb0.png

Comment: thank you, I missed that Name. problem solved!